# How do you organize bibtex citations?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, best-practices, jabref

I use JabRef sofar on multiple files, each for a specific topic and then include all the needed (mostly all of them) at the end of file with a single line:

```
\bibliography{bib/foo,bib/bar,..}
```

Drawbacks so far: having multiple files to include (solution: topic separation via tagging)

Comment: This looks borderline for off-topic for me. It's really about how you work, not about (La)TeX or BibTeX.

Comment: I also struggled with myself, but I assume here many people with knowledge on Bibtex, that may have interesting suggestions for me. Do you know a better place to ask this?, where I don't get windows answers like: "Don't use Bibtex use Papers2, Crossref, Endnote, ...".

Comment: Placing your .bib files in a subdirectory below your current working directory seems like a poor idea to me. Better to store them someplace like `LOCALTEXMFHOME/bibtex/bib/own`. (Naturally, you'll (probably) have to create the "own" subdirectory before you can store files in it.) Update TeX's filename database (`texhash` will do if you run texlive) if that's necessary, and you should be in business.

Comment: @Mico: there is _no_ need for a `texhash` for the users `texmf` directory. It is searched recursively

Comment: @Herbert: Good point!

Comment: @Mico I do almost that, but keep my real `.bib` file in my home folder (so I can see it easily). I then use a symlink to connect it to my `TEXMFHOME` directory. (I have Admin rights on my Windows system, so can create links on all platforms.)

Comment: What is the advantage to put bibs inside the texmf tree? Currently I have same but outside of texmf and under version control in my home and then symlinking to the project's bib/ directory. However, my original question was more if multiple files are better than single ones and by now I would conclude that a single file is better..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your aim is being able to typeset bibliographies for specific topics, with [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) there's no need to store your bibentries in topic-specific `.bib` files. Instead, use the `keywords` field to specify a comma-separated list of keywords (topics) for each bibentry. You may then combine `\nocite{*}` with `\printbibliography[keyword=<keyword>]` to produce a topic-specific bibliography.

Comment: Keeping separate files may also simplify bibliography management (especially if you are doing it by hand). For example, if you want to give a coworker all your references of a certain topic, with separate bibliographies you just can send him the file. With one big bile for everything, you have to create a new bibliography specifically for that purpose. Of course that's less of an issue if you use specialized bibliography management software.